# How to draw the normal to the plane in PCL

Tags: geometry, point-cloud-library

I have the plane equation describing the points belonging to a plane in 3D and the origin of the normal X, Y, Z. This should be enough to be able to generate something like a 3D arrow. In pcl this is possible via the viewer but I would like to actually store those 3D points inside the cloud. How to generate them then ? A cylinder with a cone on top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a line perpendicular to the plane:

You have the plane equation. This gives you the direction of the normal to the plane. If you used PCL to get the plane, this is in ModelCoefficients. See the details here: [SampleConsensusModelPerpendicularPlane](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model_perpendicular_plane.html#details)

The first step is to make a line perpendicular to the normal at the point you mention (`X`,`Y`,`Z`). Let (`NORMAL_X`,`NORMAL_Y`,`NORMAL_Z`) be the normal you got from your plane equation. Something like.

```
pcl::PointXYZ pnt_on_line;
for(double distfromstart=0.0;distfromstart<LINE_LENGTH;distfromstart+=DISTANCE_INCREMENT){
  pnt_on_line.x = X + distfromstart*NORMAL_X;
  pnt_on_line.y = Y + distfromstart*NORMAL_Y;
  pnt_on_line.z = Z + distfromstart*NORMAL_Z;
  my_cloud.points.push_back(pnt_on_line);
}
```

Now you want to put a hat on your arrow and now `pnt_on_line` contains the end of the line exactly where you want to put it. To make the cone you could loop over angle and distance along the arrow, calculate a local x and y and z from that and convert them to points in point cloud space: the z part would be converted into your point cloud's frame of reference by multiplying with the normal vector as with above, the x and y would be multiplied into vectors perpendicular to this normal vectorE. To get these, choose an arbitrary unit vector perpendicular to the normal vector (for your x axis) and cross product it with the normal vector to find the y axis.

The second part of this explanation is fairly terse but the first part may be the more important.

**Update**

So possibly the best way to describe how to do the cone is to start with a cylinder, which is an extension of the line described above. In the case of the line, there is (part of) a one dimensional manifold embedded in 3D space. That is we have one variable that we loop over adding points. The cylinder is a two dimensional object so we have to loop over two dimensions: the angle and the distance. In the case of the line we already have the distance. So the above loop would now look like:

```
for(double distfromstart=0.0;distfromstart<LINE_LENGTH;distfromstart+=DISTANCE_INCREMENT){
   for(double angle=0.0;angle<2*M_PI;angle+=M_PI/8){
      //calculate coordinates of point and add to cloud
   }
}
```

Now in order to calculate the coordinates of the new point, well we already have the point on the line, now we just need to add it to a vector to move it away from the line in the appropriate direction of the angle. Let's say the radius of our cylinder will be 0.1, and let's say an orthonormal basis that we have already calculated perpendicular to the normal of the plane (which we will see how to calculate later) is `perpendicular_1` and `perpendicular_2` (that is, two vectors perpendicular to each other, of length 1, also perpendicular to the vector (NORMAL_X,NORMAL_Y,NORMAL_Z)):

```
//calculate coordinates of point and add to cloud
pnt_on_cylinder.x = pnt_on_line.x + 0.1 * perpendicular_1.x * 0.1 * cos(angle) + perpendicular_2.x * sin(angle)
pnt_on_cylinder.y = pnt_on_line.y + perpendicular_1.y * 0.1 * cos(angle) + perpendicular_2.y * 0.1 * sin(angle)
pnt_on_cylinder.z = pnt_on_line.z + perpendicular_1.z * 0.1 * cos(angle) + perpendicular_2.z * 0.1 * sin(angle)
my_cloud.points.push_back(pnt_on_cylinder);
```

Actually, this is a vector summation and if we were to write the operation as vectors it would look like:

```
pnt_on_line+perpendicular_1*cos(angle)+perpendicular_2*sin(angle)
```

Now I said I would talk about how to calculate `perpendicular_1` and `perpendicular_2`. Let K be any unit vector that is not parallel to (`NORMAL_X`,`NORMAL_Y`,`NORMAL_Z`) (this can be found by trying e.g. `(1,0,0)` then `(0,1,0)`).

Then

```
perpendicular_1 = K X (NORMAL_X,NORMAL_Y,NORMAL_Z)
perpendicular_2 = perpendicular_1 X (NORMAL_X,NORMAL_Y,NORMAL_Z)
```

Here `X` is the vector *cross product* and the above are vector equations. Note also that the original calculation of pnt_on_line involved a vector *dot product* and a vector summation (I am just writing this for completeness of the exposition).

If you can manage this then the cone is easy just by changing a couple of things in the double loop: the radius just changes along its length until it is zero at the end of the loop and in the loop distfromstart will not start at 0.

Comment: would it by any chance be possible to expand a bit on the cone generation part ... any help is appreciated

Comment: Hello - if you let me know what you've got so far I can probably help in the right direction. I'll add a bit more though soon in the area I guess might be helpful, time permitting.

Comment: I was able to get it working by simply treating the 0.1 coefficient as a variable f(distfromstart) and only making circles towards the upper end of the plane normal. f(distfromstart) heads towards 0 as you finish off the distance iterations. thank you very much kind Sir